# Setting Properties in Directshow DMO "Constant FrameRate Conveter" in C#

Tags: c#, directshow, frame-rate, ms-media-foundation, dmo

```
Has anyone any code examples on how to set the properties of the 'Constant Framerate Converter' DMO filter.  I am using it in a graph and wish to programmatically control output framerate.  When I try to access IAMStreamConfig, it errors.
```

Answer (score 1):

You perhaps mean [Frame Rate Converter DSP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff819100). The thing is that it is not a full DirectShow filter, and is not basically a DirectShow component at all. It is a [Digital Signal Processor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff819501%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) with dual DMO/MFT interface.

DirectShow provides a wrapper to wrap DMOs and make them available in DirectShow environment, but these DMOs are made without this thought in mind. To use them in DirectShow you most likely need your own custom wrapper filter.

And there is no IAMStreamConfig interface available, you should be using IPropertyStore - this is behavior by design.

Comment: Even I'm stuck on how to use it in my application? I'm trying to use it with MediaFoundation to perform 3:2 pull-down (convert 24 fps to 30 fps). But I couldn't find any code samples/help demonstrating its use. How do I feed in a sample at 24 fps and get sample output at 30 fps?